# Include unicode text under square root symbol

Tags: math-mode, unicode

How can I get unicode text to appear under the **square-root** symbol?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\myfont[Script=Devanagari,Scale=1.0]{Sanskrit 2003}

\begin{document}
Normal text: $\sqrt{hello}$ \\
Testing unicode text under square root: $\sqrt{1.1{\myfont भू सत्तायाम् }}$
\end{document}
```

The above fails to print any of the unicode text in sanskrit:
[image: Output generated]

Comment: Does `$\sqrt{1.1\text{\myfont भू सत्तायाम् }}$` work? (needs `\usepackage{amsmath}`)

Comment: Also, be aware, that the glyphs in `$\sqrt{hello}$` come from the math font, not from the text font (compare `\textit{different}` and `$different$`).  If you want to use a text font, you have to switch to text mode first using `\text{...}`.

Comment: Hi @HenriMenke Your solution with `\usepackage{amsmath}` works. If you post it as a solution I will accept it. Thanks